# Using sympy to take the jacobian wrt symbolic matrix of a function that returns a scalar

Tags: python, sympy, calculus

I am trying to take the jacobian of a scalar function with respect to a matrix

```
w = sym.MatrixSymbol('w',2,1)
g = sym.Matrix([sym.log(1 + sym.exp(sym.MatMul(w.T,w)))])
grad_g = g.jacobian(w)
```

this returns a jacobian vector of `[0,0]` which is incorrect.

I attempted a non-symbollic implementation here:

```
w1, w2 = sym.symbols('w_1, w_2')
w = sym.Matrix([w1, w2])
g = sym.Matrix([sym.log(sym.Matrix([1]) + sym.exp(w.T * w))])
grad_g = g.jacobian(w)
```

where I get an error that says: `NotImplementedError:` with 0 further information.

Would love any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
In [130]: w = sym.MatrixSymbol('w',2,1) 
     ...: g = sym.Matrix([sym.log(1 + sym.exp(sym.MatMul(w.T,w)[0, 0]))]) 
     ...: grad_g = g.jacobian(w)                                                                                                  

In [131]: grad_g                                                                                                                  
Out[131]: 
⎡      2      2            2      2    ⎤
⎢   w₀₀  + w₁₀          w₀₀  + w₁₀     ⎥
⎢2⋅ℯ           ⋅w₀₀  2⋅ℯ           ⋅w₁₀⎥
⎢──────────────────  ──────────────────⎥
⎢     2      2            2      2     ⎥
⎢  w₀₀  + w₁₀          w₀₀  + w₁₀      ⎥
⎣ ℯ            + 1    ℯ            + 1 ⎦
```

Note that in sympy functions like exp and log do not generally expect matrix arguments. You can use indexing e.g. `M[0, 0]` to convert a 1x1 matrix to a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out for the non-symbollic case:

```
w1, w2 = sym.symbols('w_1 w_2')
w = sym.Matrix([w1, w2])
g = sym.log(1 + sym.exp(w.T * w)[0])
grad_g = sym.Matrix([g]).jacobian(w)
```

had to index into the matrix return by sym.exp not make the 1 a matrix.

I would love to know if there is a way to do this with sym.MatrixSymbol though, so let me know